# An integral involving hypergeometric functions and leading to a sum with Gamma functions

Tags: definite-integrals, gamma-function, hypergeometric-function

I am interested in computing the following integral

$$
I=\int_{-1}^{1}\mathrm{d} u~_2F_1\left(-k,\alpha+k-\frac{1}{2};\alpha, 1-u^2\right)(1-u^2)^{\alpha-1}u^{2m}
$$

where $_2F_1$ is the standard hypergeometric function, $k,m$ are positive integers and $\alpha>0$. I want to prove that it's equal to $0$ for $m>k$.

I wrote the hypergeometric function as a polynomial, 
$$
~_2F_1\left(-k,\alpha+k-\frac{1}{2};\alpha, t\right)=\sum_{l=0}^{k}\binom{k}{l}(-1)^l \frac{\Gamma(\alpha-1/2+k+l)}{\Gamma(\alpha-1/2+k)}\frac{\Gamma(\alpha)}{\Gamma(\alpha+l)}t^l
$$

and got the expression

$$
I=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(1/2+m)}{\Gamma(\beta+k)}\sum_{l=0}^{k}\binom{k}{l}(-1)^l \frac{\Gamma(\beta+k+l)}{\Gamma(\beta+1+l+m)}
$$
where $\beta:=\alpha-1/2$.

I am now left with trying to prove that the expression
$$
A = \sum_{l=0}^{k}\binom{k}{l}(-1)^l \frac{\Gamma(\beta+k+l)}{\Gamma(\beta+1+l+m)}
= \sum_{l=0}^{k}\binom{k}{l}(-1)^l \frac{\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(\beta+l+j)}{\prod_{i=0}^{m}(\beta+l+i)}
$$
equals $0$ when $m>k$. In this case it can also be written as 
$$
A = \sum_{l=0}^{k}\binom{k}{l}(-1)^l \frac{1}{(\beta+l+k)\ldots(\beta+l+m)}
$$

So far I've tried representing $A$ as the $m-k$th integral between $0$ and $1$ of the polynomial

$$
P(X) = X^{\beta+k}(1-X)^k = \sum_{l=0}^k \binom{k}{l}(-1)^l X^{\beta+l+k}
$$
and it's clear that the right hand side of this expression equals $A$ when integrated $m-k$ times. It isn't however clear why this is $0$.

I'm not sure I've tried the right method for this. Perhaps this is a known integral for hypergeometric functions, or a known sum for Gamma functions?